# Extend the UIImageView to be a swipeable element that can display multiple photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

i have created a simple app with two buttons and one uiimageview. 
One button takes a photo from photo library and puts it on uiimageview.
When the user adds another photo the old one should be saved and then user can swipe between these two photos.

another button takes a photo and put it on uiimageview.

So now i'm really confused about swiping between photos. I read that uiimageview can contain only one image. Also, i read that i need to add uiScrollView to UiImageView, but i don't know how they work together.

should i delete my UIImageView and then create ScrollView instead of it?

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


    - (IBAction)pickPhoto:(id)sender {

        picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker1.delegate = self;
        [picker1 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

        picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker2.delegate = self;
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"not avaialbe");

        }
        [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    - (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

So i have added a method that allows user to swipe left or right and he can see different pictures, however, i had to hard code my images into the code. But i want to select images from the photo library, then these images will be saved in the array and then if user adds more pictures he has a choice to swipe through his old images.

Here is my code for swiping through the images

```
- (IBAction)Swipe:(id)sender {
    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ayat.png", @"qwe.png",@"4444", @"15", nil];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    switch(direction)
    {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            imageIndex++;
            break;

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            imageIndex--;
            break;
        default:
            break;


    }
    imageIndex = (imageIndex <0)?([images count] -1 ):
    imageIndex % [images count];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];

}
```

but here i added pictures to my project.

Comment: Ok, you need some method for the user to select images. You'll need to create a mutable array to remember the array of selected image, and then use that array like you are above in your swipe action. Doesn't your code above simply cause the image to switch to the new image without any side-slide animation? That doesn't seem very intuitive. A collection view would let you do a very natural gesture that would move one image over and slide the next image into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that a UIImageView can display only a single image.

There are various ways to handle this. One would be to use a UIPageViewController. That would enable you to set up side-swipe based paging between pages of content. There is a sample app from Apple called PhotoScroller (it used to be linked from the Xcode help system. With Xcode 6, apple seems to have removed all sample code. You'll have to search the net for the sample app. That app also includes tiled rendering, which is likely overkill for your application, but it does show how to set up a page view controller.

You could also use a UICollectionView, or create your own custom view that manages a set of views.

Actually now that I think about it a UICollectionView set up for paging might be your best bet.

Comment: I have a question. Instead of creating UICollectionView, can i create just a UIScrollView and whenever user takes a photo from library, this photo will be put inside the UIScrollView. 

I need to display only one photo at a time, and if the user selects another photo from library, he should be able to swipe between his old photo and his new one.

Comment: Sure, but it's more work. A collection view is designed to manage items that the user can scroll between. Collection views have a paging option that gives you the behavior you want pretty much for free.

Comment: If you want to do this yourself you would create a scrollview and add it to your view controller's content view. You'd then add image views to the content view of the scroll view. Making it handle the swipe and page behavior will be a fair amount of work however. I'm telling you, a collection view is the way to go.